# Prepositions "в" and "во"

Tags: предлоги

What is the rule for changing the preposition "в" into "во"? I cannot think about any way to explain it.

First of all, semantically they seem to be perfectly identical:

> (дежурить) во вторник, в среду.

Both forms can be used with the same word:

> (увидеть) во сне, (провалиться) в сон.

Even phonetic conditions may be the same:

> (пройти) во двор, (стучаться) в дверь

Any ideas?

Comment: To make matters even more interesting, `в` doesn't always become `во` even when the following word starts with `в` itself, for example _в вечность_ or _в ворота_.

Comment: Similar pair: «к» and «ко» (к дому, ко дну, ко вторнику, к среде, к/ко двору, к двери).

Comment: And while I'm at it: «с» and «со»: со вторника, сo среды, с понедельника, с/со двора, с двери, со дна.

Comment: And there are [74 instances of «в дворе»](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_created&out=normal&dpp=10&spd=10&seed=17378&nodia=1&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&lang=ru&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E2&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%E4%E2%EE%F0&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=4) in the corpus. So «двор» seems ambivalent in all the cases, leaning to «-о» in some cases and to «-» in others.

Comment: @Артём Багинский no, it is not ambivalent. You can гулять во дворе, but you cannot гулять в дворе. On the other hand you can жить в дворе and жить во дворе but the letter only if you are a homeless person, see my answer below.

Comment: "Неужели вам приятно жить в дворе, который выглядит как помойка?", "Муж заупрямился не потому, что не хочет жить отдельно, а потому, что не хочет жить в дворе с вашими родителями." vs. "Лабрадор зимой может жить во дворе.", "Как приучить хорька жить во дворе?"

Answer (score 10):

Rosenthal et al., *Справочник по правописанию, 
произношению, литературному редактированию, §199.9*:

> В условиях контекста возможны дублеты типа *в введении – во введении*. Добавление гласного `-о` к предлогу, состоящему из одного согласного звука или оканчивающемуся на согласный, наблюдается в ряде случаев:
>
> 1. перед односложным словом, начинающимся со стечения согласных, с беглым гласным в корне, например: *во сне (ср.: в сновидениях), во рту (ср.: в ртутных испарениях), во льну (ср.: в льнотеребилках), ко мне (ср.: к мнимой величине)*;
> 2. часто после предлогов *в* и *с*, если с этих же согласных начинается последующее стечение согласных, например: *во власти, во внушении, со слезами, со словами, со страху*;
> 3. в отдельных фразеологических выражениях, например: *во сто крат, изо всех сил, во главе войск, как кур во щи*;
> 4. в текстах, имеющих оттенок торжественности, например: *Во дни сомнений, во дни тягостных раздумий о судьбах моей родины... (Тургенев)*;
> 5. в сочетаниях официального стиля, например: *во избежание, во исполнение, во имя (перед начальным гласным слова).*

which means:

> Context may allow doublets like *в введении – во введении*. The letter `-о` is appended to a preposition consisting of (or ending with) a consonant in following cases:
>
> 1. before a monosyllabic word with a fleeting vowel in the root, which starts with a consonant cluster, e. g. *во сне (cmp.: в сновидениях), во рту (cmp.: в ртутных испарениях), во льну (cmp.: в льнотеребилках), ко мне (cmp.: к мнимой величине)*;
> 2. often, after prepositions *в* and *с*, if the following word starts with a consonant cluster with the same initial letter, e. g. *во власти, во внушении, со слезами, со словами, со страху*;
> 3. in established phraseologisms, e. g. *во сто крат, изо всех сил, во главе войск, как кур во щи*;
> 4. in sonorous discourse, e. g. *Во дни сомнений, во дни тягостных раздумий о судьбах моей родины... (Turgenev)*;
> 5. in official language phraseologisms, before an initial vowel, e. g. *во избежание, во исполнение, во имя*

Since this preposition is clitical (phonetically dependent on the word it governs), `о` appears in places where historical `ъ` would be in a strong position.

Comment: Yes, but these rules can be violated: 1. во двор has no unstable (fugitive) vowel, в дни doesn't have to have "о" after the preposition 2. в воскресенье doesn't get "o" after the preposition, 3. just a bunch of exceptions, 4. and 5. it is not always the case, because even high-style, solemn and official texts one can find prepositions without "о" ("в избежание" is also ok).

Comment: However, if there is no better answer, I'll accept this answer =)

Comment: @Olga: *во двор*, *во мрак*, *во благо* etc. are I think rather part 3, established expressions. Those can even also be sematically distinctive: *в сколько (раз)* vs. *во сколько (часов)*. *Воскресенье* does not start with a consonant cluster, so part 2 won't apply.

Comment: These are not "rules" for producing correct speech, but classes of «-о»-prepositions. Any use of such preposition will, allegedly, fall into one of these classes.

Comment: @АртёмБагинский: with the rule 3, it's not that hard.

Comment: Class, not rule :-) Of course it's not hard, it's a real life language, not some lojban or klingon, why should it be hard?

Comment: @Quassnoi Could you translate that quoted part in your answer? :P

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use both preposition "в" and "во" with prepositional case while locative may mandate using "во".

Some examples:

- мыши **во** льну гнездо совьют (Locative, you cannot use "в" here)
- **в/во** льне много целлюлозы (Prepositional)
- **во** сне я видел родной дом (Locative)
- **в/во** сне много пользы (Prepositional)
- я находился **во** внушении (Locative)
- дело не **в/во** внушении (Prepositional)
- этот участок - **во** владении государства (Locative)
- **в/во** владении радоактивными материалами нет никакой опасности (Prepositional)
- гулять **во** дворе (Locative)
- жить **в** дворе без газона (Prepositional)
- **во** рту много зубов (Locative)
- **в** (этом) рте она видела черты отца (Prepositional)
- **во** главе страны стоит надежный человек (Locative)
- **в** главе государства пробудилась жалось (Prepositional)

I think that preposition "в" can be used instead of "во" in ambiguous situations to empathize that the prepositional case is used rather than locative. Note that with some words you can only use "в" in any case.

Comment: interesting theory, but «я живу в России» refuse to conform to the *mandate*. the question becomes: in which cases does locative mandate «во». And what about accusative(?) («я поехал в Россию», «я вошёл в/во двор»)?

Comment: @Артём Багинский as you can see I wrote in the answer that you can only use "в" with some words.

Comment: so the "rule" is: with *some* words we use «в» and with others we use «во»? Then the question remains: in which cases locative mandates and prepositional allows «во»?